# Unable to upload & send an image to the server (ReactJS & JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to include the option to upload an image in my app (React in the front side and NodeJS in the server one). The issue I am facing is that I am not able to send the file to the server. I saw other questions in this site and tutorials in other websites but I can't find what I'm doing wrong, so I hope you can, please, help me out.

This is part of my React code:

```
export default class DisplayPicture extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // etc
  }

  onImageChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const img = event.target.files[0];
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", img);

      this.service
        .uploadPicture(formData) // API call through a service
        .then((backAnswer) => console.log(backAnswer))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Please, upload an image</p>
        <input type="file" name="image" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I take a look at what the service sends to the server, it is an empty object and the server gets obviously the same in req.body and an "undefined" when looking for req.file.

I know the usual thing is to upload files by using a form, but I've already tried and got the same result, so I shared the shorter version.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `formData.append('image', img, img.name);` instead of `formData.append('image', img);`. In my project I use `formData.append('file', file, file.name)` and it works.

Comment: @PavloMyroniuk I have just tried and I still get the same problem, as the filename parameter is optional. Thanks for the suggestion though!